# $\frac{x^2+y^2}{4} \leq e^{x+y-2}$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I remember from singlevariable calculus, that if we have a $[a,b]$ interval and $f,g$ are some functions and $f(a)<g(a)$, and $f'(x)\leq g'(x)$, then $f(x) \leq g(x)$.

Now, can I use this theorem with multivariables? If yes, how?

For instance I have $\frac{x^2+y^2}{4} \leq e^{x+y-2}$, where $x,y \geq 0$. I feel like it would be very easy to prove this with this theorem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whare are the domains for $x$ and $y$ ? $\mathbb{R}$ ?  $\mathbb{_+}$, $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it, they are both greater or equal than 0. I edited the post, thanks!